# Changing Javascript attribute (inline in HTML) based on screensize - like CSS Media Queries

Tags: javascript, size, screen, media

I'm utilizing Flexislider2 for a responsive site, and unsure how to write the code for a challenge I have. I am well versed in HTML and CSS, however not very good at javascript (yet, still learning :>).

The site is utilizing CSS media queries at a few breakpoints, and all CSS responsiveness is fine(just mentioning for fyi).

However, there are some attributes in flexislider that are set inline within the HTML (within  tag), that I need to change at the same breakpoints.

I need to dynamically change the value for itemWidth at certain screen widths (including on change, not just load) in the same fashion css Media Queries would kick in.

So my question is, how can I change the value of that attribute when the screen size is (or changes) to
        <=960px
and
        <=780px
and
        <=480px

Basically I need the value to change at the same time my CSS media queries hit, which just for reference are:
        @media screen and (max-width: 960px)
        @media screen and (max-width: 780px)
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px)

Here is the javascript which currently is inline with the HTML document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){ 
      $('#testimonial_carousel').flexslider({
             animation: "slide",
             animationLoop: false,
             slideshow: false,
             randomize: false,
             itemWidth: 472,
             itemMargin: 0,
             start: function(slider){
               $('body').removeClass('loading');
             }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `flexslider` but can you just not specify an itemWidth and use only CSS? `#testimonial_carousel img { width:472px; }` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.resize(function(){
    if(screen.width <= 480){
        //do something
    }else if (screen.width <= 780){
        //do something else
    }else if(screen.width <= 960){
        //do final thing
    }
})
```

You can find more about these [hear for resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and right [here for screen.width().](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html)

The second link in particular is very instructive for what you are trying to do.